# Show records belonging to treeview's selected last node

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, treeview

I have a treeview that displays a few nodes, say 5 or so. When the final node is selected, I want to display records belonging to that final node (linked via a foreign key) inside of a listbox.
So the structure would be

```
  Treeview          Listbox
    -1             -Object belonging to 5
    --2            -Object belonging to 5
    ---3
    ----4
    -----5
```

My question is if such a comperation between these two controls is even possible and if I'm going about it the smartest way.
I can't find anything about it (getting actual data from the last selected node in the treeview is already pretty hard on how to find a how to). Any tips in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this exactly the way you're trying to by using attached properties, but it's a bit of a clumsy way of going about it. What you really should be doing is using data binding.

Your TreeView is, presumably, bound to some kind of data structure in your view model (data context), and what class that is should (again, presumably) be able to easily ascertain whether or not a particular given item is the deepest/last one in the tree. So create a property in that class and bind the TreeView's SelectedItem to that, so that it gets updated whenever the user selects an item in the Tree. Next, create another property for your ListBox to bind to. When your first property gets set, it either sets this second property to the currently selected item if it's the last in the list, or sets it to null if it isn't.

By doing this you de-couple your logic from your view and you make something that's much easier to debug, test and modify in future.